# Spring Cloud Function - Separate routing-expression for different Consumer

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-function

I have a service, which receives different structured messages from different message queues. Having `@StreamListener conditions` we can choose at every message type how that message should be handled. As an example:

We receive two different types of messages, which have different header fields and values e.g.

Incoming from "order" queue:

```
Order1: { Header: {catalog:groceries} }
Order2: { Header: {catalog:tools} }
```

Incoming from "shipment" queue:

```
Shipment1: { Header: {region:Europe} }
Shipment2: { Header: {region:America} }
```

There is a binding for each queue, and with according `@StreamListener` I can process the messages by catalog and region differently

e.g.

```
@StreamListener(target = OrderSink.ORDER_CHANNEL, condition = "headers['catalog'] == 'groceries'")
public void onGroceriesOrder(GroceryOder order){
...
}
```

**So the question is**, how to achieve this with the new Spring Cloud Function approach?

At the documentation https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_event_routing it is mentioned:

`Also, for SpEL, the root object of the evaluation context is Message so you can do evaluation on individual headers (or message) as well …​.routing-expression=headers['type']`

Is it possible to add the routing-expression to the binding like (in `application.yml`)

```
onGroceriesOrder-in-0:
  destination: order
  routing-expression: "headers['catalog']==groceries"
```

?

**EDIT after first answer** 
If the above expression at this location is not possible, what the first answer implies, than my question goes as follows:

As far as I understand, an expression like `routing-expression: headers['catalog']` must be set globally, because the result maps to certain (consumer) functions.

How can I control that the 2 different messages on each queue will be forwarted to their own consumer function, e.g.

```
Order1 --> MyOrderService.onGroceriesOrder()
Order2 --> MyOrderService.onToolsOrder()
Shipment1 --> MyShipmentService.onEuropeShipment()
Shipment2 --> MyShipmentService.onAmericaShipment()
```

That was easy with `@StreamListener`, because each method gets their own `@StreamListener` annotation with different conditions. How can this be achieved with the new `routing-expression` setting?
?

Comment: Hi @Danny did you find how to achieve it ?

Comment: I need the same behavior. but, apparently `routing-expression:...` can not be applied on the binding level.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the fact that the above is not a valid expression, but I think you meant `headers['catalog']==groceries`. If so, what would you expect to happen from evaluating it as the only two option could be true/false. Anyway, these are rhetorical but helps to understand the problem and how to fix it.

The expression must result in a value of a function to route TO. So. . .

`routing-expression: headers['catalog']` - assumes that the actual value of `catalog` header is the name of the function to invoke

`routing-expression: headers['catalog']==groceries ? 'processGroceries' : 'processOther'` - maps value 'groceries' to 'processGroceries' function.

Comment: Thank you, this leads to a follow up question, see in the **"EDIT after first answer"** block

Comment: Yes, to get the equivalent of 'condition' we had in StreamListener (and more) you can use `routing-expression` as message header. Refer to this test for an example - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/function/RoutingFunctionTests.java#L110

Comment: it's rather useless, as you have to define this header when you're sending (creating) a message. So you need to embed function name (architecture detail) in a message. If message comes from external system, it knows nothing about architecture of my system, so it doesn't know, which header to set. Do you suggest to make functions names based on what's in header? The whole popwer of messaging is decoupling, which in yoour solution doesn't happen. You tie message with consumer function name

Comment: I never said or suggested any of what you just said. The expression allows you to evaluate anything including message header and based on that determine the function definition. Just like in provided example function `echo` will be invoked if message's content type is `text/plain`. It certainly does the same thing as with legacy annotation approach while keeping your actual code clean from infrastructure details.  So what coupling you are referring to???

Answer (score 0):

For a specific routing, you can use MessageRoutingCallback strategy:

> MessageRoutingCallback
>
> The MessageRoutingCallback is a strategy to assist with determining
> the name of the route-to function definition.
>
> ```
> public interface MessageRoutingCallback {
>   FunctionRoutingResult routingResult(Message<?> message);
>   . . .
> }
> ```
>
> All you need to do is implement and register it as a bean to be picked
> up by the RoutingFunction. For example:
>
> ```
> @Bean
> public MessageRoutingCallback customRouter() {
>   return new MessageRoutingCallback() {
>       @Override
>       FunctionRoutingResult routingResult(Message<?> message) {
>           return new FunctionRoutingResult((String) message.getHeaders().get("func_name"));
>       }
>   };
> }
> ```

[Spring Cloud Function](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/blob/main/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-function.adoc)